# validates_acceptance_of not working for boolean attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to put a validation on a checkbox field. The checkbox must be checked.  If checked then it is true, If unchecked it is false.

For some reason, even when the user checks the checkbox field: it does not pass validation:

```
# models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :like
  validates_presence_of :message
  validates_acceptance_of :active
end
```

The attribute `active` is a boolean of type `tinyint`.

```
# relevant part of views/comments/_form.html.erb
...
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :active %><br>
  <%= f.check_box :active %>
</div>
```

Below shows what happens, even when I check the checkbox:

[image: Even when checked: still throws validation error]

Strangely: If I change the `validates_acceptance_of :active` validation to: `validates_numericality_of :active, equal_to: 1`
 It works as expected.

How come I can't use `validates_acceptance_of`?  What am I missing here?

[Rails validation documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_acceptance_of)

Comment: Do you have column "active" in DB?
And have set boolean type for active column like this:
add_column :comments, :active, :boolean, :default => false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_acceptance_of):

> Configuration options: ...
>
> :accept - Specifies value that is considered accepted. The default value is a string "1", which makes it easy to relate to an HTML checkbox. This should be set to true if you are validating a database column, since the attribute is typecasted from "1" to true before validation.

So try:

```
validates_acceptance_of :active, accept: true
```